# Sci-fi short story where a man travels to another planet on business and meets a woman

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story in school, around 2013-2016, and I think about it every now and then, but I can't remember what it was called. Around that time I believe we also read a short story called "[The Cold Equations](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-cold-equations/)", by Tom Godwin. Maybe that could somehow help find it.

There was a man who went on a solo business trip to another planet. I think it was to observe what life was like there for a few days.  As far as I can remember, the "aliens" on the other planet looked just like normal humans. He could breathe air and he did not wear a space suit.

It had different people from different planets around, and it was common for people to travel to different planets for business or a vacation. He stayed in a hotel or something like that, and he ended up meeting a woman, definitely romantic.

He was intrigued by her, because there was something about her that was special,and they met several more times, and I think the story was told to us largely through a journal he was writing back in his room, detailing his experience on this planet.

I think they first met at a restaurant, while before hand he was drinking alcohol and reflecting on the amazing technology around him, and then they maybe went on a walk together another time they met.  I think at the end he was trying to find her before he left but couldn't. I'm not exactly sure.

What made it interesting to me was that it seemed like they wouldn't be able to be together, or that they wouldn't meet again after the man left the planet. There was a time limit on the trip, and it was like two people being at the right place at the right time in order to meet, never to happen again. It was like a once in a life time thing.

Comment: We don't know when you go to school, please specify roughly which year it was.

Comment: A story where nothing interesting happened that you can recall, and yet you keep thinking about it every now and then? There must be more to the story than you've told us. Why don't you tell us everything you can remember about the story.

Comment: @KCWong Probably in between 2013-2016

Comment: @user14111 I've typed everything I can think of, but I'm still racking my brain, so if anything else comes up, I'll edit the post.

Comment: @nobes do you remember anything about how he got to the planet? Were their any aliens? Any robots? What was the planet like? Did he need a spacesuit there? Etc. Anything at all you remember might be the thing that jogs someone's memory.

Comment: Take a look at [this list of tips](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335), maybe something there will trigger a memory or two

Comment: @WiggotheWookie I updated my post with some more information. Thanks for the questions to get me thinking!

Comment: This is very generic plot that you can find in lots of stories. BTW, Arther C. Clarke’s short story “The Star” has a man who travels to a distant planet for scientific observation and meets a woman there.